# How to make close button to work on Zurb Foundation Reveal modal from ajax source?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation, reveal.js

Adding the close button is as simple as adding a line of HTML to the ajax source:

```
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

However the button won't work if I don't reload the reveal.js and initialise it on the ajax source.

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).foundation();
</script>
```

Since I have already load the reveal.js and initialise it on the parent html page, is there any way I could make it work without having to reload the js and initialise it?

Comment: Actually it should work fine because if you have parent child html files ultimately they get combined into a single page, are you seeing any error message when you inspect element. I think there is jquery conflict issue or may be something else. it would be nice if you could share your link or jsfiddle